# Nik Collection plugin not working with Photoshop CC 2017

Tags: photoshop, os-x, plugin

The Title says it all. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue in OSX? If so, is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the CC 2017 update, Adobe has moved the installation location of Photoshop -- it's now normally found in /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2017/.  Unfortunately, this also moves the location of the Plug-ins folder.

You could try manually moving the Nik plug-ins yourself, but the easiest solution is probably just to download and re-install.  (The installers can be found at https://www.google.com/nikcollection/.)

Answer (score 1):

I use a Mac w/ latest OS X.  Had same problem w/ PS CC 2017.  Partially solved the problem by uninstalling the Nik suite (uninstaller downloaded from Nik website) and reinstalling the Nik suite (download from Nik).  The result is I can now use CEP 4 and SEP 2 (two of the favorites in the suite) in both LR and PS. AEP 2 also appears work.  Define 2, Sharpener Pro 3 and Viveza 2 crash both LR and PS.

Answer (score 1):

Please update to 2017.1.1 (released this week). This addresses compatibility issues between Nik and Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I followed file path Macintosh HD>Applications>Adobe PS 2015.5>Plug-ins

I then copied the plug-ins in that folder over to the Adobe PS 2017 Plug-ins folder.

Restarted the application and the plug-ins were back!

Answer (score -1):

If you downloaded CC PS 2017 through Adobe Cloud the older version is still on your computer. In my case I found older version at C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014\Plug-ins. Under Plug-ins you will find a google folder with all of the Nik plug ins. Drag that google file to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017\Plug-ins. You now have Nik Software that works with PS 2017. You're welcome.

Comment: OP is asking about OS X, not Windows.